# LibGDX/Tiled rendering order

Tags: libgdx, tiled

I'm using LibGDX and Tiled. I need to render a Texture for my repeated background, then myTiled map and finally the sprites.

My problem is that if I put `mapRenderer.render()` between `batch.begin()` and `batch.end()`, the background texture is not being rendered.
If I render the map before or afterthe batch, some objects are hided.

So the logic of what I want to do is:

```
public void render(float delta) {
  // update

  // clear screen

  batch.begin();

  // draw repeated background texture

  // draw map
  mapRenderer.setView(camera);
  mapRenderer.render();

  // draw sprites

  batch.end();
}
```

Any idea what I might be missing and how to fix it?

**Edit**

Followup question, to make sure that what I'm asking is valid.
I was under the impression that calling `batch.begin()` and `batch.end()` multiple times was inefficient. But from what I've been searching it seems that it's not. I was confusing it with creating more than one SpriteBatch.
So I guess it's fine to do more then one begin/end call in each frame?
Sorry if my question is trivial, but I'm new to LibGDX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, there is no other solution than to call it multiple times. That is, to render your background, the map, and the sprites.

I assume all of them have different textures anyway, so there won't be any performance difference.

```
batch.begin();
// draw repeated background texture
batch.end();

// draw map
mapRenderer.setView(camera);
mapRenderer.render();

batch.begin();
// draw sprites
batch.end();
```